# Allow selected option value to appear in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have multiple forms gathering information from tables in a database from drop downs. This is the code I'm working with and it works fine. It shows the appropriate data in the dropdowns.

```
    <?php 
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "proj_user", "my*password", "lrobinson");
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT description FROM services");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value=\"service1\">" . $row['description'] . "
</option>";
        }
    ?>
```

There's another page that displays a table which grabbed the data from the previous page and its dropdowns. Instead of showing the actual selection, such as "PHP tutoring", it always says "service1".

How can I go about having displaying the actual choice in the drop down and not have it always say "service1"?

Sorry for such a vague question, but it's difficult to explain without screenshots. I'll post any additional data to help answer this question.

Edit*
This first screenshot shows the drop downs with the proper choices that I want to be shown in the table. The second screenshot shows the information gathered from those drop boxes with the incorrect information.
[image: This shows the drop downs with the proper choices]

[image: This is what shows on the new page with the incorrect data.]

Comment: use the row for it

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I thought the variable is doing that.

Comment: you could do it another way as `while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){ $said_row = $row['the_column']; $other_row = $row['other_col']; .....}` and use that variable, type of thing and echo `$said_row` etc.

Comment: Is "service1" the first option of the select box? Do you mean it is reseting when changing to another page? If so you'll need to save the state, for example using $_SESSION

Comment: The selection box references another table in the database and actually shows the different data. selection1 is not in those referenced tables.

Comment: I posted images for my issue. Hopefully these do a better job of explaining my issue.

Comment: looks like service1 is the ID of the selected option, and on your table you want to display the description, just like you do in the dropdown? For that you can use a JOIN in the query which you use to fetch the table data, and join to your services table on the ID, then use the joined "description" field in your table.

Comment: @ADyson I've never used a JOIN option before. Would I be adding that in the echo line?

Comment: no it's part of your SQL query